# How to compare number Strings?

Tags: java, string

I have an array of length X of number Strings ("32", "49", "2", ...) and I need to find the largest number in that array and return the location ( array[3] is the largest number)

is there a library like array[0].isLessThan(array[3])? or something similar?

program so far:

```
int max 0

for(i=1; i<X; i++){

if(array(max).isLessThan(array[i]))
     max = i;
}
```

Comment: Convert it to integers using `Integer.parse(String s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend casting the values to integers as you compare two values.

You will need to keep track of the max as well as the index. This solution assumes all values are non-negative (because I set max to -1), but you easily change max to int min or something like that.

```
int max = -1;
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int value = Integer.parse(array[i]);
    if (value > max)
    {
        max = value;
        index = i;
    }
}
```

At this point you have the index of the highest value in the array. If there are multiple max values, you could store an array of indices.

Comment: Strictly speaking, isn't this a 'conversion' rather than a 'cast'?

Comment: "Casting" seems to be a misuse of terminology here; casting refers to changing the type of a value on the bytecode level (for example, a double that is cast to an int will afterwards be represented by 4 bytes), while what is done here is called "parsing", i.e. a semantical transformation of information that is represented as a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. Please correct me if Im wrong.

```
int max 0

for(i=0; i<X; i++){

     if(array[i]).isLessThan(array[i+1]))
         max = i+1;
     else
         max = i
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A more complex solution for the sake of Acamedic interest :) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] anArrayOfStrings={"199999","32", "33", 
"10000","45","99999","72987","0","92"};
    Test test=new Test();
    Test.CX cx=test.new CX();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(anArrayOfStrings,cx) ;
    System.out.println("Item="+anArrayOfStrings[(anArrayOfStrings.length-1)]);
}

class CX<String> implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {



        if( Integer.parseInt((java.lang.String) arg0) > 
   Integer.parseInt((java.lang.String) arg1)){

            return 1;

        }else if(Integer.parseInt((java.lang.String) arg0) < 
  Integer.parseInt((java.lang.String) arg1)){
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: You're parsing the same strings multiple times.

Comment: @whiskeysierra gr8

Comment: @whiskeysierra This solution is pertaining to use of Comparator  which should be the standard way to do such sorting it instead of having a custom logic. Algorithmically speaking an extra computation of parseInt will effect the run time a bit but the number of Steps involved is the same - So this is a better solution rather than having a custom logic to find the greatest number